# How do I fix my air compressor tank that is constantly leaking?

Tags: pipe, air-compressor

I have an air compressor model WL660501AJ which had the 1/4 nipple snap in the tank resulting in an air leak. I removed the remaining portion and tried to replace the pipe with plumber's tape on the threads but the tank continues leaking around the nipple. How do I stop the tank from leaking? I've included a pic of the leaking tank.

[image: compressor showing leaking connection]

Comment: Hard to see if that is a boss in a tank that cracked or the threads. If the threads get another peace of pipe. Even from another place. Why the threading machine may have been set a tad tight so you cannot get a good seal. I have found under sized nipples more often in the last few years than ever before, possibly being made some place else who knows but I have seen it quite often, if your nipple has more than 3 or 4 wraps of tape and is not sealing prior to being fully inserted it is two small or straight thread. Your nipple needs to be NPT in most cases and a straight thread or undersized is

Comment: You said that the nipple snapped. Based on the pic, I'd guess that something in the surrounding metal _also_ has a hair-line crack in it and it's leaking there. No amount of PTFE tape or pipe dope will seal it because it's not the threads where the leak is happening.  Did you tap the tank itself to get that pipe threaded in there? It looks _way_ to big to be a direct replacement for a '1/4" nipple'. If my theory is correct, then you'd have to weld metal around the fitting to close the gap, but then you'd have to pressure test to ensure your weld would hold 150PSI, and that can be dangerous.

Comment: It may not be NPS tapered thread. t would be difficult to seal an NPS-straight thread combination.